# OBS Shuts down when IDLE

Tags: obs-studio

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and OBS Studio and it runs almost perfectly, I can record for hours and It won't crash while I'm recording.

The only issue comes when I pause the recording, I leave the computer to go to eat, or do something else and then when I come back OBS Studio is still opened but minimized, when I try to maximize it the program is closed instantly (Sometimes it is closed when I come back and it is not minimized).

I am using OBS 28.0.3
[image]

I have never received any error message, OBS always shuts down silently without letting me know what happened.

This is my last Logfile:

```
20:09:47.439: Platform: Wayland
20:09:47.457: CPU Name: AMD Ryzen 5 5600G with Radeon Graphics
20:09:47.457: CPU Speed: 3892.933MHz
20:09:47.457: Physical Cores: 6, Logical Cores: 12
20:09:47.457: Physical Memory: 31465MB Total, 10525MB Free
20:09:47.457: Kernel Version: Linux 5.15.0-52-generic
20:09:47.457: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "22.04"
20:09:47.457: Session Type: wayland
20:09:47.458: Qt Version: 6.2.4 (runtime), 6.2.4 (compiled)
20:09:47.458: Portable mode: false
20:09:47.479: OBS 28.0.3 (linux)
20:09:47.479: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.506: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.506: audio settings reset:
20:09:47.506:   samples per sec: 48000
20:09:47.506:   speakers:        2
20:09:47.506:   max buffering:   960 milliseconds
20:09:47.506:   buffering type:  dynamically increasing
20:09:47.510: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.510: Initializing OpenGL...
20:09:47.510: Using EGL/Wayland
20:09:47.510: Initialized EGL 1.5
20:09:47.519: Loading up OpenGL on adapter AMD AMD RENOIR (LLVM 13.0.1, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-52-generic)
20:09:47.519: OpenGL loaded successfully, version 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5, shading language 4.60
20:09:47.538: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.538: video settings reset:
20:09:47.538:   base resolution:   1920x1080
20:09:47.538:   output resolution: 1920x1080
20:09:47.538:   downscale filter:  Bicubic
20:09:47.538:   fps:               30/1
20:09:47.538:   format:            NV12
20:09:47.538:   YUV mode:          Rec. 709/Partial
20:09:47.538: NV12 texture support not available
20:09:47.538: P010 texture support not available
20:09:47.540: Audio monitoring device:
20:09:47.540:   name: Default
20:09:47.540:   id: default
20:09:47.540: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.548: No AJA devices found, skipping loading AJA UI plugin
20:09:47.548: Failed to initialize module 'aja-output-ui.so'
20:09:47.554: No AJA devices found, skipping loading AJA plugin
20:09:47.554: Failed to initialize module 'aja.so'
20:09:47.557: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-captions.so'
20:09:47.561: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-output-ui.so'
20:09:47.564: A DeckLink iterator could not be created.  The DeckLink drivers may not be installed
20:09:47.564: Failed to initialize module 'decklink.so'
20:09:47.681: [pipewire] Available captures:
20:09:47.681: [pipewire]     - Desktop capture
20:09:47.681: [pipewire]     - Window capture
20:09:47.696: [obs-browser]: Version 2.18.5
20:09:47.696: [obs-browser]: CEF Version 103.0.5060.134 (runtime), 103.0.0-5060-shared-textures_143.2591+g4204d54+chromium-103.0.5060.134 (compiled)
20:09:47.726: FFMPEG VAAPI supported
20:09:47.753: [obs-websocket] [obs_module_load] you can haz websockets (Version: 5.0.1 | RPC Version: 1)
20:09:47.753: [obs-websocket] [obs_module_load] Qt version (compile-time): 6.2.4 | Qt version (run-time): 6.2.4
20:09:47.753: [obs-websocket] [obs_module_load] Linked ASIO Version: 101201
20:09:47.757: [obs-websocket] [obs_module_load] Module loaded.
20:09:47.776: os_dlopen(libvlc.so.5->libvlc.so.5): libvlc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
20:09:47.776: 
20:09:47.776: [vlc-video]: Couldn't find VLC installation, VLC video source disabled
20:09:47.776: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.776:   Loaded Modules:
20:09:47.776:     vlc-video.so
20:09:47.776:     text-freetype2.so
20:09:47.776:     rtmp-services.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-x264.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-websocket.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-vst.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-transitions.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-outputs.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-libfdk.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-filters.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-ffmpeg.so
20:09:47.776:     obs-browser.so
20:09:47.776:     linux-v4l2.so
20:09:47.776:     linux-pulseaudio.so
20:09:47.776:     linux-pipewire.so
20:09:47.776:     linux-jack.so
20:09:47.776:     linux-capture.so
20:09:47.776:     linux-alsa.so
20:09:47.776:     image-source.so
20:09:47.776:     frontend-tools.so
20:09:47.776:     decklink-output-ui.so
20:09:47.776:     decklink-captions.so
20:09:47.776: ---------------------------------
20:09:47.776: ==== Startup complete ===============================================
20:09:47.826: All scene data cleared
20:09:47.826: ------------------------------------------------
20:09:47.828: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 15.99.1'
20:09:47.828: pulse-input: Audio format: s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels
20:09:47.828: pulse-input: Started recording from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor'
20:09:47.828: [Loaded global audio device]: 'Desktop Audio'
20:09:47.828: PipeWire initialized
20:09:47.828: Switched to scene 'Scene'
20:09:47.828: ------------------------------------------------
20:09:47.828: Loaded scenes:
20:09:47.828: - scene 'Scene':
20:09:47.828:     - source: 'Screen Capture (PipeWire)' (pipewire-desktop-capture-source)
20:09:47.828: ------------------------------------------------
20:09:47.873: [pipewire] Screencast session created
20:09:47.887: [pipewire] Asking for desktop
20:09:47.913: [pipewire] desktop selected, setting up screencast
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Server version: 0.3.48
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Library version: 0.3.48
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Header version: 0.3.48
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Created stream 0x5569b3a6d550
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Stream 0x5569b3a6d550 state: "connecting" (error: none)
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Playing stream 0x5569b3a6d550
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Stream 0x5569b3a6d550 state: "paused" (error: none)
20:09:47.916: [pipewire] Negotiated format:
20:09:47.916: [pipewire]     Format: 8 (Spa:Enum:VideoFormat:BGRx)
20:09:47.916: [pipewire]     Modifier: 72057594037927935
20:09:47.916: [pipewire]     Size: 1920x1080
20:09:47.916: [pipewire]     Framerate: 0/1
20:09:47.921: [pipewire] Stream 0x5569b3a6d550 state: "streaming" (error: none)
20:12:26.022: ==== Shutting down ==================================================
20:12:26.023: pulse-input: Stopped recording from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_06_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor'
20:12:26.023: pulse-input: Got 31273 packets with 7503496 frames
20:12:26.023: [pipewire] Stream 0x5569b3a6d550 state: "paused" (error: none)
20:12:26.024: [pipewire] Stream 0x5569b3a6d550 state: "unconnected" (error: none)
20:12:26.055: All scene data cleared
20:12:26.056: ------------------------------------------------
20:12:26.121: [obs-websocket] [obs_module_unload] Shutting down...
20:12:26.121: [obs-websocket] [obs_module_unload] Finished shutting down.
20:12:26.124: [Scripting] Total detached callbacks: 0
20:12:26.125: Freeing OBS context data
20:12:26.125: 1 views remain at shutdown
20:12:26.141: == Profiler Results =============================
20:12:26.141: run_program_init: 500.745 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 2.905 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 0.518 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 412.04 ms
20:12:26.141:    ┣obs_startup: 19.332 ms
20:12:26.141:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 345.359 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0.058 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0.108 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 34.188 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::InitOBSCallbacks: 0.004 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::InitHotkeys: 0.038 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣obs_load_all_modules2: 235.671 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(aja-output-ui.so): 0.076 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(aja.so): 0.06 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink-captions.so): 0 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink-output-ui.so): 0 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink.so): 0.088 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(frontend-tools.so): 49.633 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(image-source.so): 0.008 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-alsa.so): 0.003 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-capture.so): 0.001 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-jack.so): 0.003 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-pipewire.so): 0.976 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-pulseaudio.so): 0.002 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-v4l2.so): 1.469 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-browser.so): 0.056 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-ffmpeg.so): 0.557 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┃ ┗nvenc_check: 0.432 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-filters.so): 0.018 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-libfdk.so): 0.003 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-outputs.so): 0.004 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-transitions.so): 0.007 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-vst.so): 0.003 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-websocket.so): 4.163 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-x264.so): 0.002 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(rtmp-services.so): 0.448 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(text-freetype2.so): 0.012 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┃ ┗obs_init_module(vlc-video.so): 0.085 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetOutputs: 0.136 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::CreateHotkeys: 0.024 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::InitService: 0.752 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┣OBSBasic::InitPrimitives: 0.07 ms
20:12:26.141:      ┗OBSBasic::Load: 52.01 ms
20:12:26.141: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0 ms, median=0 ms, max=0.002 ms, 99th percentile=0.001 ms, 100% below 25 ms
20:12:26.141: audio_thread(Audio): min=0.005 ms, median=0.023 ms, max=0.146 ms, 99th percentile=0.05 ms
20:12:26.141: obs_graphics_thread(33.3333 ms): min=0.078 ms, median=0.318 ms, max=9.29 ms, 99th percentile=0.837 ms, 100% below 33.333 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┣tick_sources: min=0.001 ms, median=0.003 ms, max=0.035 ms, 99th percentile=0.008 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┣output_frame: min=0.055 ms, median=0.141 ms, max=3.655 ms, 99th percentile=0.586 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┃ ┗gs_context(video->graphics): min=0.055 ms, median=0.141 ms, max=3.655 ms, 99th percentile=0.586 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┃   ┣render_video: min=0.014 ms, median=0.034 ms, max=2.127 ms, 99th percentile=0.072 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┃   ┃ ┗render_main_texture: min=0.011 ms, median=0.033 ms, max=2.104 ms, 99th percentile=0.07 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┃   ┗gs_flush: min=0.002 ms, median=0.091 ms, max=0.701 ms, 99th percentile=0.542 ms
20:12:26.141:  ┗render_displays: min=0.002 ms, median=0.16 ms, max=9.189 ms, 99th percentile=0.546 ms
20:12:26.141: =================================================
20:12:26.141: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
20:12:26.141: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25.015 ms, median=25.071 ms, max=25.892 ms, 99.2885% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 0.711462% higher)
20:12:26.141: obs_graphics_thread(33.3333 ms): min=32.694 ms, median=33.333 ms, max=33.98 ms, 100% within ±2% of 33.333 ms (0% lower, 0% higher)
20:12:26.141: =================================================
20:12:26.145: Number of memory leaks: 0
```

Comment: This is possibly related to [this bug](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/6990) where the solution is currently to switch back to X-Org instead of Wayland, although I haven't tested for a while it may have been patched.